# How to define a generic type that accept interfaces/types have a specific property?

Tags: typescript, generics

I have two following example interfaces:

```js
interface A {
  id: string;
  propA: number;
}

interface B {
  id: string;
  propB: number;
}
```

And I have this following generic function that only accepts the interfaces having `id` property:

```js
function foo<T>() {
  // ...body
}
```

I don't want `A` and `B` to extend a super interface that only has `id` property.
How can I define the `T` type?

Comment: `{ id: string }`?

Comment: Are you looking for a [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) as in `function foo<T extends {id: string}>() {}`?  It's hard to tell because a generic function accepting no parameters doesn't make a lot of sense in isolation.  Maybe you could make your [mcve] a little less miminal and demonstrate how `foo()` could do something with `T` so I'm sure what you're asking?